# Create a remote Git branch as mirror for a specific git-svn branch of a SVN repository

Tags: git, svn, git-svn, git-remote

I cloned an existing svn repo off a remote server locally using git-svn's `git svn clone <orig_svn_repo_path>`. I now want to setup a remote repo for only a particular branch out of several branches of the locally cloned repo say `<cloned_repo>/branches/<branch_to_clone>`. Is this possible to do? The rest of the repo is pretty humongous in terms of size and as there is only that particular branch that I have to work on, I'd rather just setup a remote mirror for it. Also if that is possible, how would I then update the original svn repo with the branch being worked upon and also push my changes to the remote git branch (repo) to keep it in sync with the local branch (that is updated onto the svn repo) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make commits to SVN (using `git svn dcommit`), you should *not* use a `git clone` of any git repository.

You should instead use a `git svn init` command with the appropriate parameters so that only the SVN directory you're interested in is fetched, and then a `git svn fetch`. You can do this as many times as you like.

If you do a `git clone` of a repository which is set up to track SVN, you have an issue: git-svn modifies the body of commits it sends to Subversion via `dcommit`, adding in a `git-svn-id` line. This is a type of history rewriting. So if you have a SVN-oblivious repository which pushes to the SVN-aware one, which then pushes to Subversion itself, you're going to have an issue when you try to do a `git push` the second time.

Just to make sure we're clear, the problem is that the first repository will rewrite history when it does a `dcommit`. So any new changes pulled down to another git repo from that point on will have a different commit hash, requiring forced pulls/pushes. It's exactly like what would happen if someone were to rebase publicly-visible changes: see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2046748/383402).

Fundamentally, git-svn is designed to be used with the SVN repository itself serving as the "central" repo.

If you want a *read-only* copy of Subversion, never doing another `dcommit` (or at least not keeping the second git repo up to date after you do a `dcommit` from the first), then you're fine. Just do a `git clone` with a refspec restricted to the branch in which you're interested.

Comment: I'm fairly new to git and git-svn. The purpose of the clone was to have a look into side-by-side of the older branches during early stages of development. Now that you mention it, a git svn fetch sounds appropriate to get the branch im interested. That said, since i have the clone now, is there no way to have a git remote for the svn branch?

Comment: @Kevin You're going to run into trouble if you ever fetch changes which have not been `dcommit`ed, then try to fetch those same changes again after the `dcommit` is done using `git fetch`/`git pull`. There's no problem if you just do two totally independent repositories both connected to SVN and use `git svn fetch` or `git svn rebase` to keep up-to-date.

Comment: So if i understand correctly, a `git svn init` followed by a `git svn fetch` would be the safest way to be able to `dcommit` to the original SVN ? Will a `git push` then work for the remote as in push the master(fetched svn branch) to the remote git repo? Please correct me if im wrong.

Comment: The two repository approach sounds fair considering i'm still coming to terms with the whole thing. I'd just like to have a separate remote on which I only fetch & push changes once the changes are dcommitted to svn from the other working copy. Will that create any problems?

Comment: @Kevin There is no problem as long as you only fetch+push changes which have already been `dcommit`ed. Once they're rewritten once (to add the `git-svn-id` metadata) they're safe.